# Rails running total column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, cloud9-ide

I currently am working on my first rails project after working through multiple tutorials.

I am trying to build a webpage to track my savings goal for the next 6 months.

essentially the site consists of a form input where I input the date I put money into savings and the amount. This site then updates a line graph to show the current savings vs. the goal line.

So far I have successfully built the form and database (using postgresql) and have created the chart which displays the goal and accepts input from the form.

The problem I have is that the input values are displaying as discrete numbers and not a cumulative sum up that month (i.e. week 4 should be the sum of savings from weeks 1 to 4).

I considered initially having a 3rd column in the db called amount_cum and put some lines in the page load method in the controller, that means the database would recalculate at each page load which may be slow...

Any advise would be appreciated, should I be looking to modify the model or the controller?

Lay on the wise words

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
def home
 @pages = Pages.new
 @progress = Pages.order(:week)
 @goal = Goals.all
end

def create
 @pages = Pages.new(pages_params)
 weeks_year=Date.parse(params[:pages][:week]).strftime("%U")

 @pages = Pages.new(pages_params.merge(:week => weeks_year))


if @pages.save
  flash[:success]="Savings Uploaded Successfully"
   redirect_to root_path
else
   flash[:danger]=@pages.errors.full_messages.join(", ")
   redirect_to root_path
 end
 end  
private
 def pages_params
 params.require(:pages).permit(:week, :amount)
end

end
```

And model file:

```
 class Pages < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :week, presence: true
  validates :amount, presence: true
 end
```

my view file - I use chartkick gem to generate the chart:

```
  <%= line_chart [
  {name: "Amount Saved", data: @progress.group(:week).sum(:amount)},
  {name: "Goal Savings", data: @goal.group(:week).sum(:amount) }] %>
```

Screen shot of the application so you can see how the graph is to be displayed against the goal.
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTJxl.jpg)

Comment: It might be easier to help if you could post some code snippets

Comment: added - be easy on me :P

Comment: so you need cumulative sums by months?

Comment: at this stage im using weeks as my x-axis so i am converting the date into the week of the year. In my head I either want the controller to perform a sum of all entries in the database with a week value less than the current object and then save that number to the database, or have a 3rd column that is a running total. whichever is easier to implement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, you could use `inject` in the view when generating the chart:

```
<% saved = [] %>
<% @progress.inject(0) do |sum, page| %>
<%   current = sum + page.amount
<%   saved << current %>
<%   current # the return value is passed in as `sum` in the next iteration %>
<% end %>
<%= line_chart [
      {name: "Amount Saved", data: saved},
      {name: "Goal Savings", data: @goal.group(:week).sum(:amount) }]
%>
```

Shorter but a little awkward:

```
<% saved = [] %>
<% @progress.inject(0) { |sum, page| (saved << sum + page.amount).last} %>
<%= line_chart [
      {name: "Amount Saved", data: saved},
      {name: "Goal Savings", data: @goal.group(:week).sum(:amount) }]
%>
```

You didn't post any info on the `Goal` model, but you could use a similar technique if you are also looking to plot the incremental increase in the goal each week.

EDIT:
If you need an array of arrays, you could try something like this (forgive me, I'm doing this on my phone)

```
<% @progress.inject(0) { |sum, page| (saved << [page.week, sum + page.amount]).last.last} %>
```

EDIT 2:
I don't think `inject` should modify the original @progress array (if that's what you're asking), but for the sake of argument (and diagnostics), try the following (we can certainly pretty this up if it works):

```
<% saved = [] %>
<% cum_sum = 0 %>

<% @progress.map do |page| %>
<%   cum_sum += page.amount %>
<%   saved << [page.week, cum_sum] %>
<% end %>
<%= line_chart [
      {name: "Amount Saved", data: saved},
      {name: "Goal Savings", data: @goal.group(:week).sum(:amount) }]
%>
```

Comment: Just tried that - having the line_chart function in the loop causes it generate a new graph for every iteration (I have about 50 graphs now on my page).

Comment: There is also a way to do this with custom SQL (`select`ing a running total column), but I'm not sure it would be more clear or more performant.

Comment: I see. Try the latest revision.

Comment: My apologies, battery almost dead and no charger, did it very quickly, but should be the gist. No warranties though  ;-)

Comment: Given that we are now just generating a new array of data to give to the chart, it may make more sense to move the bulk of this code into the model, or perhaps a helper. Will take another look tomorrow after I get my charger ;-)

Comment: yeah that was my initial thought - got rails errors from your code:  

undefined local variable or method `current' for #<#<Class:0x00000004c80128>:0x00000003836b68>
Did you mean?  current_page?

Comment: If you were using the second version, try again, I just revised.

Comment: I get a "Error Loading Chart: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined" I think it is because "saved" is an array of single values - i.e. does not have a weeks set of values to plot against.

I also read that chart kick requires data to be "arrays of arrays" in this article: https://github.com/ankane/chartkick/issues/219

Comment: Try the most recent edit. I can't test it as I'm on my mobile, but it should be the gist

Comment: No problem, glad it's working. I will update with some additional explanation.

Comment: is there any chance that the inject overwrites the existing value in the array rather than generating a new pair? for example by default weeks 1-27 are populated with the current cumulative sum, when a user adds a value for a week it generates a new pair that sits alongside and its causing a bit of havoc in the plotting of the graph. for instance at the moment I have [9, 3611], [9, 3611], [9, 3811], [9, 4922] as values in the array

Comment: @timboon See EDIT2

Comment: Although I may need you to elaborate on "when a user adds a value for a week it generates a new pair that sits alongside..." - not sure I get what you mean, but sounds important ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler way to calculate sums in Rails - you don't have to use `inject`, you can simply call [`sum`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-sum) on the array of records. In your case it would be something like:

```
@progress.sum(:amount)
```

However, the way I interpreted your question on the first read, I thought that, you were trying to create an array of partial sums from an array of actual sums. I don't know if that's of any use for you, but anyway, here's how I would do that using Ruby's `each_with_object` and `with_index` and Rails' `sum`:

```
amounts = [100, 200, 150, 300, 120]

partial_sums = amounts.each_with_object([]).with_index do |(_, obj), i|
  obj << amounts[0..i].sum
end                      # => [100, 300, 450, 750, 870]

# Examples:
partial_sums[0]  = 100  # 1st sum - just the first element
partial_sums[2]  = 450  # 3rd partial sum
partial_sums[-1] = 870  # the total of all the amounts from the array
```

Hope you find that useful.

Comment: can this be used with hashes the same? sorry for ignorance but how would you modify this to apply to key value pairs as I still need each cumulative sum to have a key of :weeks so I can plot the two in a line graph